# Update Kerberos Cache

Tags: authentication, caching, kerberos

I have to connect to different devices simultaneously using kerberos authenication. At present using default cache(File) to store kerberos ticket which stores only one ticket at a time. But for my requirement I have to store multiple tickets. Please suggest how to update cache which stores multiple tickets and how to access them. At present kerberos tickets are accessed using kinit.

Please share the detailed steps to update the cache to handle above requirement. I am new to this space your help is much appreciated.

Below is the sample `krb5.conf` configuration file. By default File cache is used.

```
{   [logging]
         default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
         kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
         admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

        [libdefaults]
         dns_lookup_realm = false
         ticket_lifetime = 24h
         renew_lifetime = 7d
         forwardable = true
         rdns = false
         default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
         default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

        [realms]
         EXAMPLE.COM = {
          kdc = kerberos.example.com
          admin_server = kerberos.example.com
         }

        [domain_realm]
         .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
         example.com = EXAMPLE.COM

}
```

Comment: Please edit formatting of this question. When you want to use multiple Kerberos caches you can use environment variable 'KRB5CCNAME', here is documentation https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/basic/ccache_def.html.

Comment: Updating KRB5CCNAME=DIR:/tmp/ is allowing kerberos to maintain cache for multiple tickets. Thanks for you help. The above solution is working for root user. When i am running as different user  below error is coming 
bash-4.1$ kinit
kinit: Credentials cache I/O operation failed XXX while getting default ccache

Comment: The real solution would be to use a different **FILE:** for every Kerberos principal, and have each device use the appropriate ticket with a matching `KRB5CCNAME`

Answer (score 0):

Updating more information on my requirement, for example under single active directory there are 10 windows devices all share same domain name , username and password. From this network(say from one linux machine) I want access these devices using Kerberos authentication as different user but not as root user. Currently Kerberos uses default cache FILE which stores only one ticket a time. But for my requirement I want to maintain all 10 tickets and access them not as a root user.With FILE cache and as different user I am able to access device using Kerberos authentication. My application is running in multi threaded environment. Please share the detailed solution I am new to this space.